# Is there a term that describes such songs?

Tags: genre, terminology, rap, hip-hop

I've recently listened to a couple of songs and found a common beat.
A quick google search for their genre shows that they fall under the umbrella of *Hip-Hop/Rap*. 
However, searching for 'Hip-Hop/Rap' doesn't result in a songs with the same beat; I thought that there might be a more specific term for them.
Here are the songs :

- Bounce Back - Big Sean
- Help a bi*ch out - O.T. Genasis
- Moves - Big Sean
- No Limit - G eazy

Answer (score 1):

I would say mostly downtempo then chillout

Here is a sample https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw4_KmnnH6c

Comment: I'm afraid that the sample you've put and the examples in the questions are of completely different genres.

The beat, melody are much different.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term would be trap music.

> Trap is a subgenre of hip hop music that originated in the Southern United States during the early 1990s. The genre gets its name from the Atlanta slang word "trap," which refers to a place in which drugs are sold illegally. Trap music uses synthesized drums and is characterized by complicated hi-hat patterns, tuned kick drums with a long decay (originally from the Roland TR-808 drum machine), atmospheric synths and lyrical content that often focuses on drug use and urban violence.It utilizes very few instruments and focuses almost exclusively on snare drums and double- or triple-timed hi-hats. This is the signature sound of trap music.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_music

Trap is one of the most popular modern sub-genres of rap. You can tell it by the distinctive ultra-fast beat that is present in your sample songs.